# Chromebook Default Printer

Tags: chromebook

A client is having an issue with their Chromebook where every time they go to print, it defaults to "Save As PDF" every time.  Researching this online, it seems it is supposed to default to the most recently used printer, but this is not happening.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The app's default option is to export the current file as pdf. If you don't see your printer under this dropdown, the connection with the printer is not established as it should have been.

Comment: That's not the issue - he is able to go through the dialogue to get it to print to the correct machine, but it does not default over to the last printer used lime it is supposed to (according to what I've been able to find, at least).

Comment: Got it. 0 issues on my Chromebook, though. I tried multiple ways of adding,  removing, and managing printers, but whatever I do, the default option will be the last chosen. I don't even have to print the document. Choosing a destination from the dialog changes the default option for me, even if the printer is not active.
Can you check for printers at chrome://devices/?

Comment: Sounds like a glitch.  Try a settings reset: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?visit_id=1-636235551884872730-561636821&p=ui_reset_settings&rd=1